# Initialize Array with Values (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way to initialize this array in one line:

```
mulof = []
(1..1000).each {|i| mulof << i if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is using [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) :

```
mulof = (1..1000).select { |i|  i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 }
```